# MongoDB using $lookup, $unwind, $match to search

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

There are 2 collections in my mongodb named "teacher" and "course" and the structures are as below

#### teacher

```json
    {
        "rating": 4,
        "teacher_id": "123",
        "course_count": 1,
    },
    {
        "rating": 5,
        "teacher_id": "456",
        "course_count": 4,
    }
```

#### course

```json
    {
        "teacher_id": "123",
        "advanced": true,
    },
    {
        "teacher_id": "456",
        "advanced": false,
    }
```

What I want is to search is which course's teacher teaches less than 2 courses and the course's advanced is True.

### The result I want

```json
    {
        "teacher_id": "123",
        "advanced": true,
    }
```

### I have tried

```json
db.getCollection('course').aggregate([
    {"$limit": 10 },
    { "$lookup" : {
        "localField": "teacher_id" ,
        "from": "teacher" ,
        "foreignField": "teacher_id" ,
        "as": "teacher"
    }},
    {"$unwind": {path: '$teacher', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {'$match': {
        'advanced': true,
        'teacher.course_count': {'$lt': 2}
    }}
])
```

But it seems not working, can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You may find it simpler to aggregate on the teacher collection, lookup the corresponding courses, eliminate any that teach 0 or more than 2 courses, then eliminate any that teach a non-advanced course.  This should leave a 1:1 mapping between teacher and course.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
db.course.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "advanced": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "teacher",
      "localField": "teacher_id",
      "foreignField": "teacher_id",
      "as": "teacher"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "teacher.course_count": {
        "$lt": 2
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "advanced": 1,
      "teacher_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zEMqNa8gGYF)

**Note:** If you need to access `teacher` array content, you may use `$unwind` + `$project` or `$let` operator. Let me know if this solution meets you requirements

Comment: It did works on MongoPlayground with my small amount of real data, but not on my real db.It seems like query is timeout according to my large database.I am still finding something else to deal with my problem. Do you know any other solution (without 
 restriction on $lookup and $unwind is OK), thanks for your help!